# Fill In DataFrame From Other DataFrame

Tags: r, data.table

```
data1=data.frame("Group1" = sample(1:2,100,r=T),
                  "Group2" = sample(c('a','b'),100,r=T),
                  "V1" = sample(1:3, 100, r=T),
                  "V2" = sample(0:1, 100, r=T),
                  "V3" = sample(1:5, 100, r=T),
                  "V4" = sample(1:2, 100, r=T))


data2=data.frame("Group1"=c(1,1,2,2),
                  "Group2"=c('a','b','a','b'),
                  "Size"=c(900,768,651,102))
```

I wish to randomly sample columns `'V1'` to `'V4'` from `data1` and use it to fill in `data2`.

I want to sample by `'Group1'` and `'Group2'` and make n replicates for each group combination where n is defined as `'Size'` in `data2`.

The desired output should have 900+768+651+102=2421 rows. I wish to sample with replacement.

Comment: When you say sample columns, do you expect less number of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the previous question/answerr, we can the column names ('nm1') that start with 'V', do a join with the first dataset `on` the 'Group1', 'Group2', get the `sample` with `replace = TRUE`, and use that index to fill with the values of the column sampled

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- grep("^V\\d+", names(data1), value = TRUE)
setDT(data2)[data1, on = .(Group1, Group2)][,
   .(i_samp = sample(.I, Size, replace = TRUE)), by = .(Group1, Group2, Size)
         ][, (nm1) :=   data1[i_samp, nm1], .(Group1, Group2)][]
```

Comment: thanks so much! I tried this and it only output sampling for 'V4'

Comment: when i apply to my own data i get this: Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 15000000 rows; more than 1000090 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.

Comment: are you able to go into a short chat so i can share the details?

Comment: @bvowe sorry, I was offline.  Your error seems to be because the `data2` can have duplicate records in the  original dataset compared to the example.  If that is the case, by doing the `on` join, it cannot specifically point to the unique location

Comment: @bvowe One way is to either group by the 'Group1', 'Group2', and then create a string of 'Size' or a list column of 'Size', then doo the merge, finally unnest the Size